# Would a potentiometer/resistor still draw the same current

Tags: current, resistors, resistance, potentiometer, physics

This is a very basic question but here it goes:

For example we have a potentiometer going to an LED.
the current of the output of the poteniometer is lowered, but wouldn't the current of the wire connecting to the inputs of the potentiometer still have the same current? Like this poorly drawn circuit [image]
Would the red/black wire still have the same current as without/without the resistor or potentiometer? Or was I hiding under a rock this whole time and missed out on some basic law/physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Current is the same at all nodes in a series circuit. The Wires in that circuit are just very very low resistance resistors. There is n Amps going through the red wire and black wire, the same that is going through the 1kΩ Potentiometer. What they divide is the voltage. The Voltage across the whole circuit is the sum of the voltage across each node. So some tiny fraction of a volt across the red wire, some tiny fraction of a volt across the black wire, and the majority across the potentiometer.

Comment: Which means there must be a switch to truly limit the current and really 'open' or stop discharging the circuit.

Comment: @ihazgum yes. Connecting the pot to a battery directly or with wires will cause current to flow. A switch or otherwise disconnecting the wires or pot is necessary for the current to stop flowing. Of course, how much current flows depends on the total resistance or load. A 1k resistor and a 5V source would only draw 5 mA, which may be small enough for you not to care. But a battery would be drained in weeks with that.